# Can't deploy a report to SpagoBI Server

Tags: fiware, spagobi, fiware-cosmos

I'm trying to deploy a report from SpagoBIStudio 5.2.0 on a SpagoBI Server v5.1.0.

The report works perfectly in SpagoBIStudio (locally in my computer), and I successfully created the data source and the data sets using the web interface of SpagoBI Server.
Nevertheless when I click on the "Deploy" option of my ".rptdesign" file, I see the following dialog and the "Finish" button is always disabled.

[image]

For some reason I can select the correct `Datasource` but the `Dataset` dropdown list is empty and disabled. I guess this could be the problem.
The data source is a JDBC-Hive connection to Cosmos and the Datasets are defined as HQL queries in both Studio and Server.

Does anybody know why the datasets aren't listed in the deploy document wizard of SpagoBIStudio?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot finish the deploy not because of dataset but because you did not select any functionality on the tree on the right.

You don't have any functionality on server where to store your document, so you should go to server with and administrator user role,
then with the menu on the right, on the profile section, select the "functionalities management" menu and create a folder that is child of the root. Give it the permissions you need
After this operation try again the deploy and you should be able to select one funcitonality and so have finish button enabled

greetings

Answer (score 1):

the dataset selection is disabled because a Birt Report is not linked to dataset that way.
There are two ways of using datasets in Birt:
- Birt embedded datasets, that can be of several types provided by Birt (SpagoBI has no role with that)
- SpagoBIServer type dataset; these are linked to SpagoBIDataset by providing label, but this association is written inside template, during template definition.

Hope this fix your problem, I would suggest you also to take a look at SpagoBI wiki page for further informations
greetings

Giulio

Comment: Thanks Giulio. I chose the second option (created a SpagoBIServer type dataset linked by label). Nevertheless I still have the same problem: I can't "Finish" the "Deploy document wizard" and the "Dataset" drop-down list is still empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to select the dataset. Your finish button is not enabled because you haven't select the path from the functionalities tab. After selecting it will be enabled and your report will be deployed. After deployment you need to create Analytical drivers for the parameters through which your report will run.

NOTE: You must have a Active server configured under resources under SpagoBI project folder.